# AVX _mm256_sin_ps missing on OSX i7 AVX2 Retina MacBook Pro

Tags: macos, intel, intrinsics, avx

The Intel Intrinsics Guide lists _mm256_sin_ps as an available function with the header immintrin.h and the AVX flag, yet is seems to be missing from XCode / OSX.

I do have an AVX2 machine and other AVX intrinsics work fine, am I missing something obvious?

Comment: `_mm256_sin_ps` is part of the Intel MKL. You need to use either the Intel compiler or something else that supports MKL.

Comment: @Mysticial Not quite. `_mm256_sin_ps` is in SVML library, which ships with Intel compiler

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ error: ‘\_mm\_sin\_ps’ was not declared in this scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31978592/c-error-mm-sin-ps-was-not-declared-in-this-scope)