# C++ error: ‘_mm_sin_ps’ was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, optimization, sse, simd, intrinsics

I'm trying to benchmark different ways to apply a function to an array.

why is https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#expand=3260,2124,4779,4779&cats=Trigonometry&text=_sin

`_mm_sin_ps` not known to my scope but `_mm_sqrt_ps` is?

how do I make it known? And compile it without errors.

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <chrono>
#include <algorithm>
#include <valarray>
#include "immintrin.h"
#include <array>
int main()
{
    std::cout<<"start\n";
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    std::uniform_real_distribution<> dis(-1000, 1000);
    int N=100;
    while(N--)
    {   
        std::cout<<"\nN: "<<N;

    const int T1=4E6;
      { 
        int T=T1,T0=T1/4;
        std::array<float,T1> array;
        while(T--)
        {
            array[T]=dis(gen);
        }
        auto start_time = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        auto it =array.begin();
        while(T0--)
        {
            __m128 X = _mm_loadu_ps(it);
            __m128 result = _mm_sin_ps(X);
            _mm_storeu_ps(it, result);
            it+=4;
        }
        auto time2=std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now()-start_time;
            std::cout<<"\nintr1: "<<std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(time2).count();
        }
  }
    std::cout<<"\nfin\n";
    return 0;
}
```

compiler

g++ -v

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu      4.8.2-19ubuntu1' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.8/README.Bugs   --enable-languages=c,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.8 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.8 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-libmudflap --enable- plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64 --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64 --with-arch-directory=amd64 --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --enable-objc-gc --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu  --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)
```

Comment: If you declare it yourself `extern __m128 _mm_sin_ps(__m128 v1);`, does that compile?

Comment: yes but then the collector upon build complains undef. ref to _mm_sin_ps(float __vector)'

Comment: could it be that my machine simply does not know the _mm_sin_ps intrinsic? does the code compile on ur machine?

Comment: OK, so you get a linker error, which means the intrinsic is not available to your compiler.

Comment: What compiler/platform are you using?

Comment: compiler: gcc 4.8.2 i put g++ -v output inside the question

Comment: I have gcc 4.9.2 and there isn't function `_mm_sin_ps`, furthermore on the Intel page, this function is in section **SVML** and has no machine instruction. Have a look at [this project](http://gruntthepeon.free.fr/ssemath/), use a library for SSE trigonometry or implement it by yourself.

Comment: @anthony-arnold: if the linker gets involved with intrinsics, you have bigger problems.  The compiler turns each intrinsic into one CPU instruction.  Except for Intel's "fake" intrinsics which are actually vector library functions, not machine instructions, like this one.

Comment: Soon: https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/libmvec

Comment: How to enable SVML in ICC (Under Visual Studio)?

Comment: I would also mention the SLEEF project - [SLEEF: SIMD Library for Evaluating Elementary Functions, vectorized libm and DFT](https://sleef.org/). It has great performance which rivals Intel SVML and variable accuracy for the user to chose from. The only issue I found is it only supports MSVC on Windows (I'd like it to support CLang-CL as well).

Comment: Basically a duplicate of [Where is Clang's '\_mm256\_pow\_ps' intrinsic?](//stackoverflow.com/q/36636159), but this one has answers that go into more detail about implementing it yourself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`_mm_sin_ps` is part of the [SVML](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/524289) library, shipped with intel compilers only. GCC developers focused on wrapping machine instructions and simple tasks, so there's no SVML in `immintrin.h` so far.

You have to use a library or write it by yourself.
Sinus implementation:

- [Taylor series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Approximation_and_convergence)
- [CORDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CORDIC)
- [Quadratic curve](http://www.mclimatiano.com/faster-sine-approximation-using-quadratic-curve/)

Comment: thanks,i dont think that cordic can be used with sse, because of the table lookup. i will use min{int_0_pi/2 ((P_n(x)-sin(x))^2)dx, with P_n(0)=0;P_ n(pi/2)=1; with n=2 this should be the Quadratic curve

Comment: [DirectXMath](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/03/27/introducing-directxmath.aspx) in the Windows 8 SDK or later also includes a SIMD implementation of transcendental functions.

Answer (score 4):

As has already been pointed out, you're trying to use Intel's [SVML](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/524289) library.

There are however several SIMD transcendental functions in the free open source `sse_mathfun` library. The original version, which uses only SSE2 is here: http://gruntthepeon.free.fr/ssemath/ but there's a more up-to-date version here which has been updated for SSE3/SSE4 here: https://github.com/RJVB/sse_mathfun

The function you want is called `sin_ps`:

```
v4sf sin_ps(v4sf x);
```

where `v4sf` is just a typedef for `__m128`.

The original `sse_mathfun` also has `cos_ps`, `log_ps` and `exp_ps`, and the newer (RJVB) version has some additional functions for both single and double precision.

I've successfully used both versions of this library with gcc, clang and Intel's ICC (with some minor mods for the latter).

Comment: It is possible to use Intel's SVML with another compiler, but this is undocumented. Function prototypes look like this:
extern __m128  __vectorcall __svml_expf4       (__m128);
    extern __m128d __vectorcall __svml_exp2        (__m128d);
Unofficial function prototypes listed in https://github.com/vectorclass/version2/blob/master/vectormath_lib.h

Comment: Hi @Fog, any clue how to call Intel's SVML by third-party compiler like GCC? What header files should be included? What library should be linked?

Answer (score 4):

__mm_sin_ps is an intrinsic for calling SVML library(already mentioned).

In GCC SVML is available as a part of [libmvec](https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/libmvec)
 in glibc.

Functions are named according to Vector ABI, described in the link above. Sin, cos, exp, sincos, log, pow functions are available. 
Here is an example for __m128:

```
#include <x86intrin.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef union
{
  __m128  x;
  float a[4];
} union128;

__m128 _ZGVbN4v_sinf_sse4(__m128);

void main()
{
  union128 s1, res;
  s1.x = _mm_set_ps (0, 0.523599, 1.0472 , 1.5708);
  res.x =_ZGVbN4v_sinf_sse4(s1.x);
  fprintf(stderr, "%f %f %f %f\n", res.a[0], res.a[1], res.a[2], res.a[3]);
}
```

Is there any reason, why intrinsic is better than using the SVML function directly?

Comment: libmvec and SVML are not the same library