# _mm512_exp_pd with GNU compiler

Tags: c++, c, avx512

The following code works fine with the Intel compiler (version: 18.0.2), but not for the GNU compiler (version: 6.1.0):

```
#include <immintrin.h>

double ALIGN array1[8] = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0};

__m512d a1AVX = _mm512_load_pd(array1);
__m512d exp = _mm512_exp_pd(a1AVX);
```

The error message state the following: `error: ‘_mm512_exp_pd’ was not declared in this scope`. It is from the [SVML library](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=_mm512_exp_pd&techs=SVML&expand=2154).

I am using the following compiler flags: `-std=c++11 -march=knl -mtune=knl -fpic -O3 -DNDDEBUG`.

Do I miss a compiler flag here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ error: ‘\_mm\_sin\_ps’ was not declared in this scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31978592/c-error-mm-sin-ps-was-not-declared-in-this-scope)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

gcc *does* support Intel intrinsics. However, `_mm512_exp_pd` is not an intrinsic, but a function from `SVML` library, exclusive to Intel compiler. You can check full list of Intel intrinsics and `SVML` functions [here](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#).

Comment: Thanks, nice answer, but there have been some tries earlier to get SVML to work on GCC. (see https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-math-kernel-library/topic/281721). Unfortunatly something like `-mveclibabi=svml` or `-lsvml` does not work.