# _mm256_rem_epu64 intrinsic not found with GCC 10.3.0

Tags: c++, simd, avx, avx512

I try to re-write the following `uint64_t` 2x2 matrix multiplication with `AVX-512` instructions, but `GCC 10.3` does not found `_mm256_rem_epu64` intrinsic.

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <immintrin.h>

constexpr uint32_t LAST_9_DIGITS_DIVIDER = 1000000000;

void multiply(uint64_t f[2][2], uint64_t m[2][2])
{
  uint64_t x = (f[0][0] * m[0][0] + f[0][1] * m[1][0]) % LAST_9_DIGITS_DIVIDER;
  uint64_t y = (f[0][0] * m[0][1] + f[0][1] * m[1][1]) % LAST_9_DIGITS_DIVIDER;
  uint64_t z = (f[1][0] * m[0][0] + f[1][1] * m[1][0]) % LAST_9_DIGITS_DIVIDER;
  uint64_t w = (f[1][0] * m[0][1] + f[1][1] * m[1][1]) % LAST_9_DIGITS_DIVIDER;

  f[0][0] = x;
  f[0][1] = y;
  f[1][0] = z;
  f[1][1] = w;
}

void multiply_simd(uint64_t f[2][2], uint64_t m[2][2])
{
  __m256i v1 = _mm256_set_epi64x(f[0][0], f[0][0], f[1][0], f[1][0]);
  __m256i v2 = _mm256_set_epi64x(m[0][0], m[0][1], m[0][0], m[0][1]);
  __m256i v3 = _mm256_mullo_epi64(v1, v2);

  __m256i v4 = _mm256_set_epi64x(f[0][1], f[0][1], f[1][1], f[1][1]);
  __m256i v5 = _mm256_set_epi64x(m[1][0], m[1][1], m[1][0], m[1][1]);
  __m256i v6 = _mm256_mullo_epi64(v4, v5);

  __m256i v7 = _mm256_add_epi64(v3, v6);
  __m256i div = _mm256_set1_epi64x(LAST_9_DIGITS_DIVIDER);
  __m256i v8 = _mm256_rem_epu64(v7, div);
  _mm256_store_epi64(f, v8);
}
```

Is it possible somehow to enable `_mm256_rem_epu64` or if not, some other way to calculate the reminder with SIMD instructions?

Comment: That's [an SVML function, not an intrinsic for a CPU instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31978592/c-error-mm-sin-ps-was-not-declared-in-this-scope).  Don't use runtime division, use a multiplicative inverse.  (as in [What's the fastest way to generate a 1 GB text file containing random digits?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/324520) like I did for 16-bit integers.  [Why does GCC use multiplication by a strange number in implementing integer division?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41183935) is the general trick)

Comment: I was thinking AVX-512 had a 64-bit high-half multiply, but maybe that's only with AVX512-IFMA52 (https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vpmadd52huq).  For 64-bit multiply, I only see [`vpmullq`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pmulld:pmullq) like you're using.  Perhaps you can use double-precision FP and an FP inverse, or FP division, if that's precise enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Peter Cordes mentioned in the comments, `_mm256_rem_epu64` is an SVML function.  Most compilers don't support SVML; AFAIK really only ICC does, but clang can be configured to use it too.

The only other implementation of SVML I'm aware of is in one of my projects, [SIMDe](https://github.com/simd-everywhere/simde).  In this case, since you're using GCC 10.3, [the implementation of `_mm256_rem_epu64`](https://github.com/simd-everywhere/simde/blob/11d97ba487339390d39239a9b3973a63e0e7f9e1/simde/x86/svml.h#L9112-L9138) will use [vector extensions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Vector-Extensions.html), so [the code from SIMDe](https://godbolt.org/z/8o9WsrYs4) is going to be basically the same as something like:

```c
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef uint64_t u64x4 __attribute__((__vector_size__(32)));

__m256i
foo_mm256_rem_epu64(__m256i a, __m256i b) {
    return (__m256i) (((u64x4) a) % ((u64x4) b));
}
```

In this case, both GCC and clang will scalarize the operation (see [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/zdvzTxhb7)), so performance is going to be pretty bad, *especially* considering [how slow](https://uops.info/html-instr/DIV_M64.html) the `div` instruction is.

That said, since you're using a compile-time constant, the compiler should be able to replace the division with a multiplication and a shift, so performance will be better, but we can squeeze out some more by using [libdivide](https://libdivide.com/).

Libdivide usually computes the the magic value at runtime, but the [`libdivide_u64_t`](https://github.com/ridiculousfish/libdivide/blob/ef645e200bea6fb27318e8e4393892c1bfc7e9a3/libdivide.h#L136-L139) structure is very simple and we can just skip the `libdivide_u64_gen` step and provide the struct at compile time:

```c
__m256i div_by_1000000000(__m256i a) {
    static const struct libdivide_u64_t d = {
        UINT64_C(1360296554856532783),
        UINT8_C(93)
    };
    return libdivide_u64_do_vec256(a, &d);
}
```

Now, if you can use AVX-512VL + AVX-512DQ there is a 64-bit multiplication function (`_mm256_mullo_epi64`).  If you can use that it's probably the right way to go:

```c
__m256i rem_1000000000(__m256i a) {
    static const struct libdivide_u64_t d = {
        UINT64_C(1360296554856532783),
        UINT8_C(93)
    };
    return
        _mm256_sub_epi64(
            a,
            _mm256_mullo_epi64(
                libdivide_u64_do_vec256(a, &d),
                _mm256_set1_epi64x(1000000000)
            )
        );
}
```

(or on [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/7b9eh4sYz), with LLVM-MCA)

If you don't have AVX-512DQ+VL, you'll probably want to fall back on vector extensions again:

```c
typedef uint64_t u64x4 __attribute__((__vector_size__(32)));

__m256i rem_1000000000(__m256i a) {
    static const struct libdivide_u64_t d = {
        UINT64_C(1360296554856532783),
        UINT8_C(93)
    };
    u64x4 one_billion = { 1000000000, 1000000000, 1000000000, 1000000000 };
    return (__m256i) (
        (
            (u64x4) a) -
            (((u64x4) libdivide_u64_do_vec256(a, &d)) * one_billion
        )
    );
}
```

([on Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/T13PGqx9a))

All this is untested, but assuming I haven't made any stupid mistakes it should be *relatively* snappy.

If you really want to get rid of the libdivide dependency you could perform those operations yourself, but I don't really see any good reason not to use libdivide so I'll leave that as an exercise for someone else.